# Validate a form using a loop with many rows added by user

Tags: javascript, html

my first post.

I have a php form which allows the user to add multiple rows.  I got this to work and each new row adds a new text id as textid+1.

I then validate the form but need to loop validate to test each added row.

I can not figure out if I need to count the number of added rows or not, and how to construct the loop statement.

Thanks in advance

```
<script>
function validateForm() {

    var me_id = document.getElementById('me_id').value;
    var md_number = document.getElementById('md_number').value;


    if((me_id != "" | (md_number != "" & md_number != 0)) & (me_id == "" | md_number == ''| md_number == 0)){
        alert("You need both values for this to work");
        document.getElementById("me_id").focus();
        return false;
    }


}            
</script>  

<form  id="add-many-form" onSubmit="return validateForm()"  method="post">
    <div id="sectionsentree">
        <div class="sectionentree">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Quantity</label>
                        <input type="text" name="md_number" id="md_number" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="col-sm-4">    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Additional</label>
                        <input type="text" name="md_special" id="md_special" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>                                
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Quantity</label>
                        <input type="text" name="md_number2" id="md_number2" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="col-sm-4">    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Additional</label>
                        <input type="text" name="md_special2" id="md_special2" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>                                
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Quantity</label>
                        <input type="text" name="md_number3" id="md_number3" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="col-sm-4">    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Additional</label>
                        <input type="text" name="md_special3" id="md_special3" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#" class='addsectionentree'>Add new row</a></p>
```

Comment: How should your validation look? Do you just need to values of all the inputs?

Comment: The only validation I need is that ..either none or both fields in each row are filled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all inputs are in a `div` with the class *form-group*:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" name="md_number3" id="md_number3" class="form-control">
</div>
```

you can target them all via `querySelectorAll`:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-group input");

inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input.value));
```

This selector will give you a *nodelist* with the input fields where you can loop over. Unfortunately, for your check to work, you need pairs of input fields. To achieve that, we loop over the *nodelist* and push pairs to a variable, depending on their index:

```
const fields =[]

inputs.forEach((input,i) => {
  if(i==0 ||i%2 ==0) {
    fields.push({id: input.id, quantity: input.value});
  } else {
        fields[fields.length -1].additional = input.value
  }
});
```

The last step is to iterate over that array now and to throw an error when one field is filled and the other is not. If a field is empty, it's value will be an empty string:

```
fields.forEach(field => {
  if(field.additional == "" && field.quantity != "" || 
    field.additional != "" && field.quantity == "") {
      document.getElementById(field.id).focus();
  }
})
```

Comment: [{"Entree":"2","Quantity":"222"},{"Entree":"1","Quantity":"111"}]

Comment: Thanks for all the new information.  I have got most of it working.  I am just missing one bit.

using alert(JSON.stringify(fields));

My array does not contain the field id to be used to focus.

 (field.id).focus()

Comment: That was a mistake on my side. I forgot the first `fields.push` in my answer. It should look like this: `fields.push({id: input.id, quantity: input.value});`

Comment: Fantastic... I was looking into pushing something but doubt I would have ever got it myself.  I have learned loads... thanks again!